# How can I display the .chm file for all controls while Pressing F1 key in MFC Application?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, html-helper, chm

I created one MFC Application without choosing Context Sensitive Help option.

Now I want to display one .chm file(which is already created).

For this I changed the following settings:

I added HTML Help Workshop\include path in the Include Directory
I added HTML Help Workshop\lib path in the Library Directory
I added HTML Help Workshop path in the Executable Directory
I have also added:

1. `ID_HELP_FINDER`
2. `ID_HELP_INDEX`
3. `ID_HELP_USING`
4. `ID_HELP`

and included

`#include "htmlhelp.h"`

and called the `EnableHtmlHelp();` method.

But I get the error:

> "HH_HELP_CONTEXT" called without a [MAP] section.

Comment: Does your chm have a [MAP] section? Try using HH_DISPLAY_INDEX and see if that opens the chm. What tool do you use to create the chm? That said, googling the error message will give you many many hits and solutions.

Answer (score 0):

try this

HWND hwnd  = ::HtmlHelp(NULL, *T("..\xx*.chm"), HH_HELP_CONTEXT, data);

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/help/html/article.php/c6513

Comment: Now it is showing error ** C2660: 'CWnd::HtmlHelpA' : function does not take 4 arguments** it is overloaded function. I used HtmlHelpW also but it is also not working.

Comment: It is not CWD::HtmlHelp it is win32 api ::HtmlHelp http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms670172.aspx